# Skipping a pattern of elements using itertools and accompanying list

Tags: python, optimization, python-itertools, abaqus

I have some code that is slow (30-60mins by last count), that I need to optimize, it is a data extraction script for Abaqus for a structural engineering model. The worst part of the script is the loop where it iterates through the object model database first by frame (i.e. the time in the time history of the simulation) and nested under this it iterates by each of the nodes. The silly thing is that there are ~100k 'nodes' but only about ~20k useful nodes. But luckily for me the nodes are always in the same order, meaning I do not need to look up the node's uniqueLabel, I can do this in a separate loop once and then filter what I get at the end. That is why I have dumped everything into one list and then I remove all the nodes that are repeats. But as you can see from the code:

```
    timeValues = []
    peeqValues = []
    for frame in frames: #760 loops
        setValues = frame.fieldOutputs['@@@fieldOutputType'].getSubset
                    region=abaqusSet, position=ELEMENT_NODAL).values
        timeValues.append(frame.frameValue)
        for value in setValues: # 100k loops
            peeqValues.append(value.data)
```

It still needs to make the `value.data` calls unnecessarily, about ~80k times. If anyone is familiar with Abaqus odb (object database) objects, they're super slow under python. To add insult to injury they only run in a single thread, under Abaqus which has its own python version (2.6.x) and packages (so e.g. numpy is available, pandas is not). Another thing that may be annoying is the fact that you can address the objects by position e.g. `frames[-1]` gives you the last frame, but you cannot slice, so e.g. you can't do this: `for frame in frames[0:10]: # iterate first 10 elements`.

I don't have any experience with itertools but I'd want to provide it a list of nodeIDs (or list of True/False) to map onto the setValues. The length and pattern of setValues to skip is always the same for each of the 760 frames. Maybe something like:

```
    for frame in frames: #still 760 calls
        setValues = frame.fieldOutputs['@@@fieldOutputType'].getSubset(
                    region=abaqusSet, position=ELEMENT_NODAL).values
        timeValues.append(frame.frameValue)
        # nodeSet_IDs_TF = [True, True, False, False, False, ...] same length as       
        # setValues
        filteredSetValues = ifilter(nodeSet_IDs_TF, setValues)  
        for value in filteredSetValues: # only 20k calls
            peeqValues.append(value.data)
```

Any other tips also appreciated, after this I did want to "avoid the dots" by removing the `.append()` from the loop, and then putting the whole thing in a function to see if it helps. The whole script already runs in under 1.5 hours (down from 6 and at one point 21 hours), but once you start optimizing there is no way to stop.

Memory considerations also appreciated, I run these on a cluster and I believe I got away once with 80 GB of RAM. The scripts definitely work on 160 GB, the issue is getting the resources allocated to me.

I've searched around for a solution but maybe I'm using the wrong keywords, I'm sure this is not an uncommon issue in looping.

**EDIT 1**

Here is what I ended up using:

```
    # there is no compress under 2.6.x ... so use the equivalent recipe:
    from itertools import izip
    def compress(data, selectors):
        # compress('ABCDEF', [1,0,1,0,1,1]) --> ACEF
        return (d for d, s in izip(data, selectors) if s)
    def iterateOdb(frames, selectors): # minor speed up
        peeqValues = []
        timeValues = []
        append = peeqValues.append # minor speed up
        for frame in frames:
            setValues = frame.fieldOutputs['@@@fieldOutputType'].getSubset(
            region=abaqusSet, position=ELEMENT_NODAL).values
            timeValues.append(frame.frameValue)
            for value in compress(setValues, selectors): # massive speed up
                append(value.data)
        return peeqValues, timeValues

    peeqValues, timeValues = iterateOdb(frames, selectors)
```

The biggest improvement came from using the `compress(values, selectors)` method (the whole script, including the odb portion went from ~1:30 hours to 25mins. There was also a minor improvement from `append = peeqValues.append` as well as enclosing everything in `def iterateOdb(frames, selectors):`.

I used tips from: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips

Thanks to everyone for answering & helping!

Comment: I would really like to help but with the code you provide it is nearly impossible. I would need something that I can run and measure. By the way, have you tried [profiling](http://pythonhosted.org//line_profiler/)? Maybe that would give you a hint where the real problem is.

Comment: With the given code, it is nearly impossible to tell what's happing.

Comment: Thanks @Ali, I'll try the suggestions below first and if they don't provide a huge speed up I'll try to maybe make some staging code as an example. The problem though is the odb is proprietary and something that works in staging code may not work for the odb. I haven't tried profiling per se but I've outputted the current times and durations between those times to a text file and this loop in particular takes the longest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not confident with itertools try using an if statement in your for loop first.

eg.

```
for index, item in enumerate(values):
    if not selectors[index]:
        continue
    ...
# where selectors is a truth array like nodeSet_IDs_TF
```

This way you can be more sure that you are getting the correct behaviour and will get getting most of the performance increase you would get from using itertools.

The itertools equivalent is `compress`.

```
for item in compress(values, selectors):
    ...
```

I'm not familiar with abaqus, but the best optimisations you could achieve would be to see if there is anyway way to give abaqus your selectors so it doesn't have to waste creating each value, only for it to be thrown away. If abaqus is used for doing large array-based manipulations of data then it's like this is the case.

Comment: You are right about creating the 'value' object, like mentioned in DrV's answer. I'll see how fast 'compress()' works, I'll set up some tests.

Comment: `compress()` was definitely the right way to go but since this was Python 2.6.x I had to use the recipe that had `izip()` inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant in addition to those in `Dunes`'s solution:

```
for value, selector in zip(setValues, selectors):
    if selector:
        peeqValue.append(value.data)
```

If you want to keep the output list length the same as the `setValue` length, then add an `else` clause:

```
for value, selector in zip(setValues, selectors):
    if selector:
        peeqValue.append(value.data)
    else:
        peeqValue.append(None)
```

`selector` is here a vector with `True`/`False`, and it has the same length as `setValues`.

In this case it is really a matter of taste which one you like. If the full iteration of 76 million nodes (760 x 100 000) takes 30 minutes, the time is not spent in python's loops.

I tried this:

```
def loopit(a):  
    for i in range(760):
        for j in range(100000):
             a = a + 1
    return a
```

`IPython`'s `%timeit` reports the loop time as 3.54 s. So, the looping spends maybe 0.1 % of the total time.

Comment: You are definitely correct that python doesn't take up much time in looping. It is Abaqus' odb object that is inefficient (it is actually a C++ object with python code that wraps around it). So if I can reduce the number of 'value' objects that are created, as well as 'value.data' calls then I'll have quite the speed up.